# When i implement Cronejob it looks like doesn't take effect

Tags: python, django, cron-task

views:

```
@scheduled_task
def daily(request):
    signals.task_daily.send_robust(sender=None)
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

signals:

```
from django.dispatch import Signal
task_daily = Signal()
```

commad:

```
from django.core import management
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(task_daily)
def clear_old_sessions(*args, **kwargs):
    management.call_command("clearsessions", verbosity=0)
    print("Old sessions cleared")
```

when i run and check if is working a have installed in on apps but sessions are not cleand and there is too much dump data